# Checkbox disable in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, checkbox

I have a table. I have a column which has only checkboxes as values in it. I have brought all values  into a table using for loop.What I did was when I enable a checkbox, I showed a message "hey" When I enable one checkbox (the message appears) but when I enable another checkbox the message disappears.The message initially comes when even one checkbox gets enabled. What I need is that  until all the checkbox gets disabled the message should be there and evenwhen one or more checkboxes are there the message should be there.I am writing my code in angular.

Here is my stackblitz link
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oswf2h?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store the input values and provide a result based on the stores values.

Example with `ngModel`:

```
checkedValues: boolean[] = this.a.map(() => false);

  get isChecked() {
    return this.checkedValues.some(b => b);
  }
```

```
<div>
    <div class="Container" style="margin-left: 10px;">
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table">
                <thead class="table_header">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Checkbox</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let b of a; let i = index">
                        <td>{{b.name}}</td>
                        <td> <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1" [(ngModel)]="checkedValues[i]">
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="isChecked">
        <h1>Hey</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

Changed stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jwpane?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Property a is used before its initialization. I am getting this error.Note: I am getting the list from a service

Comment: Then you likely need to move the `this.a.map(() => false);` into `ngOnInit` or something like that

Comment: Hey it worked thanks. Can you please explain me the code? I have some trouble understanding the code?

Comment: you have an array of booleans (`checkedValues`) in your component, which is initialized with `false` and has the same length as `a`. With `let i = index` you receive the current index of the iteration, which you pass to the `[(ngModel)]` value binding. With this binding the values are stored in the array. The getter `isChecked` provides the "summary" of the array, which only tells if the array has any true value.

Comment: get isChecked() {
    return this.checkedValues.some(c => c);
  }    I didnt understand this part alone . can u explain pls?

Comment: It returns if the boolean array has any truthy value

Comment: I get that thanks but what does the .some(b=>b) do?

Comment: some is a function on an array which checks if any element in the array fulfills the provided predicate. The predicate function is `b => b` where `b` is an element in the array, so it is a boolean. We want to return true, if the element is true. In a long way you could say `b => b === true`. Obviously that term always returns true if b is true, so `b => b`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that all your checkboxes are connected to the same boolean, so they just toggle it. When one is clicked, regardless of whick one, `ischeck` gets the value of `true`. When a checkbox is clicked, either the same one or a different one, it gets toggled again so now `ischeck` is `false`.
One possible solution is to have a different check per each checkbox, and display the message based on a logical `OR`.

See [this stackblitz solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fskzp2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) here

updated ts file:

```
  ischeck: boolean = false;
  a = [
    { name: "a", isCheck: false },
    { name: "b", isCheck: false },
    { name: "c", isCheck: false }
  ];

  checkBtn(b: { name: string; isCheck: boolean }) {
    b.isCheck = !b.isCheck;
    this.ischeck = this.a.some(c => c.isCheck); // at least one item has checked as
  }
```

and change in HTML:

```
<input type=" checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1"  (click)=" checkBtn(b)">
```

EDIT:
updated the code to simulate getting data from a service
ts simulation:

```
  a = [];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.a = [{ name: "a" }, { name: "b" }, { name: "c" }]; //returned from service
    this.a.map(v => { //data changes to add boolean
      return { ...v, isCheck: false };
    });
  }
```

Comment: I am getting data from a service. So I cant add check value as false.. Is there any other way? @PMO1948

Comment: @JoeRishwanth yes, you can map it. when you get the data from the service, map it such: data.map(d=>{return {...d, isChecked:false}})

Comment: Where Am I gonna use the "data.map(d=>{return {...d, isChecked:false}})" code in my code?

Comment: in your callback from your service. If it is an observable, use service.method().pipe(map(...)). If it is not, then if you have a=service.method(), you can do a=service.method().map(...)

Comment: can I post my service in stackblitz and update here?

Comment: yes, update your stackblitz with the service and I can help you out

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224355/discussion-between-pmo1948-and-joe-rishwanth).

Answer (score 0):

I changed up you code a bit to make it work. There could be many ways to do this, but i decided to try as little as possible changes.

Store the check state for each separate checkbox.

```
a = [
{ name: "a", check: false },
{ name: "b", check: false },
{ name: "c", check: false }
];
```

On checkBtn press receive the item from front end and go through all items to see if all are disabled

```
checkBtn(b) {
    b.check = !b.check;
    let check = false;
    this.a.forEach(item => {
      if (item.check) {
        check = true;
      }
    });
    this.ischeck = check;
  }
```

Finally pass the item from frontend

```
            <tr *ngFor="let b of a;">
                <td>{{b.name}}</td>
                <td> <input type=" checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1"  (click)=" checkBtn(b)">
                </td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: I am getting data from a service. So I cant add check value as false.. Is there any other way?@Einars Bistrovs